# Sumif Formula Result Doesn't Work as Expected

Tags: excel, sumifs

The Excel file that I'm working on has 2 sheets:
**1) Calendar Sheet**, where you can select the employee to see the number of working days, overtime, vacations, business trips, sick days, and days on leave; as in the picture.

[image: Sheet1]

In this sheet all the below cells of the calculated days for each leave type is working fine, except for the overtime as shown in the picture also for this particular employee.

**The Function** is like this:

```
=SUMIFS(LeaveTracker[Days],LeaveTracker[Employee Name],valSelEmployee,LeaveTracker[Start Date],">="&DATE(Calendar_Year,1,1),LeaveTracker[End Date],"<"&DATE(Calendar_Year+1,1,1),LeaveTracker[Type of Leave],'Leave Types'!B5)
```

Where the cell of `Leave Types` is changing according to the type.

**2) The Leave Tracker Sheet,** where the table that has the dates for each employee leaving type; as shown in the photo.

[image: Sheet2]

In this sheet the Days column has the function that counts the days for each Leave Type for an employee.

**The function is:**

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[Start Date]],[@[End Date]],7,lstHolidays)
```

This function also work for every type, except for the overtime, it gives 0 as shown in the photo for Sheet2 which should be 2.

Then I added the 2 columns (`startDay` & `endDay`) in Sheet2, which both use WEEKDAY function for the (Start Date & End Date), to get the day number in order to know that this day is an weekend (Fri & Sat).

Then, I used **This function** in Sheet1 in the overtime cell:

```
=SUMIFS(LeaveTracker[Days],LeaveTracker[Employee Name],valSelEmployee,LeaveTracker[startDay],">5",LeaveTracker[endDay],">5",LeaveTracker[Type of Leave],'Leave Types'!B8)
```

This Function also doesn't work it give 0 as in the first photo.

Comment: You have conditions `startDay>5` and `endDay<5`, if `startDay` and `endDay` are such that `endDay`>=`startDay` you will never meet both conditions so your `SUMIFS` will not have any rows meeting the conditions specified in its arguments and so will return 0

Comment: By mistake, even when I put both end & start day >5, it still the same.

Comment: Without a sample of numerical data (even just one row) which gives a zero value in your formula when you expect it to be otherwise, any attempt at diagnosis will just be guessing (as I was with my previous comment).

Comment: startDay & endDay are using WEEKDAY function for the columns Start Date & End Date, in order to get the date number, and know if that day is a weekend(Fri & Sat). **One example:** Employee name | 7/21/2017 | 7/22/2017 | Overtime | number of days for the overtime (which gives 0) | 6 | 7

Comment: My first area of suspicion would be the matches on strings: namely `Type of Leave` with `'Leave Types'!B8` and `Employee Name` with `valSelEmployee`. Trailing (and even leading) spaces can make 2 cells appear to hold the same string when they don't.

Comment: I, and others, cannot reproduce your problem since you have not shared any data.  Please read the HELP topic for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited the question with more details, from the beginning.

Comment: A value of 7 for the third argument of `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` excludes Fridays and Saturdays as non-working days. In 2017, 21 July was a Friday and 22 July a Saturday, so the `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` formula you use in `LeaveTracker` is delivering the correct result of zero in the overtime row. (This might not be the result you intend and, if so, you need to use a formula that better reflects your intention).The two `SUMIFS()` you quote, will both deliver 0 because they are adding up the values in the `Days` column for any rows containing Overtime.  There's only one row and it has a value of 0.

Comment: Yes, now, I used **this function for the Days Column in Leave Tracker:**`=IF( OR(E10="Vacation",E10="Sick Leave",E10="Business Trip"), NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[Start Date]],[@[End Date]],7,lstHolidays), NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[Start Date]], [@[End Date]])`_But the problem is that it returns the value 1 instead of 2 days. I don't know why, but I notice that the NETWORKDAYS.INTL function in the Days column misses one day in two rows: The employee with the overtime & the employee with the 6 days vacation, which should be 7._

Comment: The 2nd occurrence of `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()`   in your `IF()` treats Saturdays and Sundays as non-working days. So when applied to 21-22 July 2017 it correctly calculates a value of 1. For period 29 June to 9 July, the `IF()` should calculate 7 but (because of `1stHolidays`) only if there is no holiday day in this period falling on a working day. Generally, your overtime issue seems to be:  overtime can occur on non-working days but your calculation uses a function which excludes such days. Your choice of function appear to be the wrong one for your requirement. End-Start+1 might be better.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I used different dates with overtime and it worked; I don't know why it considered it one day with this row.